# Check if a Radio Button Selection has changed

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to learn basics of Angular and stuck with a particular doubt. I have a set of dynamically generated radio button and one of them will be selected by default.

I want to check and detect the change of selection of radio button. This might not be particularly related to angular or maybe logic based question. Below is what I have attempted.

```
$scope.selectedReason= function(radio1)
      {
         $scope.radio7=radio1.id;   // now radio7 has the value of radio7 e.g "12345"
         $scope.bankAccount=radio1;

      }

   // another function where I am checking if the selected value is not same as new value


$scope.selectedAmount= function(radioSelect)
          {
                console.log($scope.radio7);  // old value 12345 
                $scope.preselectedAccount = $scope.radio7;  // hoping to store old value 
                $scope.selectedValue = $scope.preselectedAccount;
                if ($scope.selectedValue == $scope.radio7){
                   console.log("Success");
                }
          }
```

Baiscally I am trying to store old value to a variable and check but its obvious that every time a new value comes the variable takes that value so there is not point in doing this. Any way I could pertain my old value check with new values.

**Edit:**
Input

```
 <input type="radio" id="child_{{$index}}" name="radio2" ng-model="selectedBankAccount" ng-value="bankAccount" ng-click="selectedReason(bankAccount)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `change` event for it

```
// you can pass anything in the function
<input type="radio" (change)="handleChange(child_{{$index}})" />
```

and in your TS file implement the `handleChange` function and do what you want.

```
handleChange(id) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: I have aaded how I am taking the input. Can I use `id` e.g. I know that my dymanic id will be `child_2`(not everyime) . Can I check if id is other than child_2 then allow

Comment: updated my answer, you can pass `child_{{$index}}` in the function and access the id that way

Comment: Yes that worked. I  get id of selected Radio and compared it with ng-model to check. Thank you.

Comment: I did. Just a suggestion you can check with `selectedAmount` itself. Don;t have to use change event as such.